# Reactive extensions and MouseEventArgs source

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, system.reactive

I am using RX in my WPF applications to track mouse movement.

When subscribing directly to the mouse move event I get a different source in my MouseEventArgs compared to when I use the sample method of RX.

For the sake of explanation here is a simple example:

I have a window containing a grid and a button:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <Button></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I subscribe to the mouse move event with RX:

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(grid, "MouseMove").Subscribe(mouseMoveRx);
    Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(grid, "MouseMove").Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Subscribe(mouseMoveRxSample);
}

private void mouseMoveRx(System.Reactive.EventPattern<MouseEventArgs> obj)
{
    var element = obj.EventArgs.Source as UIElement; 
    //element is System.Windows.Controls.Button
}

private void mouseMoveRxSample(System.Reactive.EventPattern<MouseEventArgs> obj)
{
    var element = obj.EventArgs.Source as UIElement;
    //element is Microsoft.Windows.Themes.ButtonChrome
}
```

The first handler is having `System.Windows.Controls.Button` as source whereas the second handler is having `Microsoft.Windows.Themes.ButtonChrome` as source.

What is the reason for the different source?

Comment: Is this behavior consistent? Or did you just see this once? Is it that you just happened to mouse over the button border? You are, after all, subscribing to the `MouseMove` event on `Grid`, so anything in the `Grid` that takes up a pixel of screen space could potentially be the event source.

Comment: This is a consistent behavior. It also does not change if I use OriginalSource instead of source.

Comment: what does .Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) do ?

Comment: @eranotzap http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html#Sample

Comment: Change your sample line to call `Do` before it samples: `FromEventPattern(...).Do(mouseMoveRxSampleDo).Sample(...).Subscribe(...);`  See if the calls to `mouseMoveRxSampleDo` exhibit the same behavior.  It sounds as if `EventArgs` is mutable and getting mutated by something after `Sample` caches it and before it is reported to your observer.  Also keep in mind `Sample` is going to jump you off the Dispatcher thread and onto a thread pool thread which may cause you some consternation (though should not cause this particular problem).

Comment: @Brandon: in the mouseMoveRxSampleDo the source is the button. So it seems you are right, something is messing with it. Any idea how to avoid that? Concerning threading: I am aware of this and I use the SubscribeOn/ObserveOn with the correct Dispatcher. The issue is not affected by that.

Comment: I wonder if the theme is being loaded/applied after the form Loaded event has fired - if you delay subscribing to both events (asynchronously so  all Loaded event handlers have run), does that change anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with WPF so take this answer with a grain of salt...

But, based on your experiment with `Do`, it appears that what is happening is that after the event fires and `Sample` caches the value, the event object is mutated presumably by WPF.

The `Remarks` section of [MouseEventArgs documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) says this:

> The attached events and the base element routed events share their
>   event data, and the bubbling and tunneling versions of the routed
>   events also share event data. This can affect the handled
>   characteristics of the event as it travels the event route. For
>   details, see Input Overview.

This seems to suggest that indeed WPF mutates the event object as it bubbles it up the element hierarchy.  Any settable property on the object is subject to this behavior.  In this case it appears that `Source` is the only thing you need to worry about.

To handle this, you effectively need to cache the `Source` value before you apply any Rx operator that introduces asynchronicity because you can only trust the `Source` property for as long as your WPF event handler is running.  The simplest way is to use a `Select` clause to capture `Source`:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(grid, "MouseMove")
    .Select(e => Tuple.Create(e.EventArgs.Source as UIElement, e.EventArgs))
    .Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Subscribe(mouseMoveRxSample);

// ...

private void mouseMoveRxSample(Tuple<UIElement, MouseEventArgs> obj)
{
    var element = obj.Item1;
    //element is System.Windows.Controls.Button
}
```